# Analyzing sentence structure

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk, impersonation

I am using NLTK to analyze lyricists' sentence structures, and I was wondering if anyone had advice on how I could use NTLK to find the most common structuring of sentences, and use this to impersonate their speech.  I have been using nltk.pos_tag(line), but it's difficult to use this information in a meaningful manner to find the most common organization of sentences.  Is there any academic writing on how you can utilize this to impersonate a person's composition of sentences?

Comment: Off the top of my head - not specifically for NTLK, but you should be able to calculate Markov chain model on the POS tags, which should give you some idea about structure. The problem is you have no idea about vocabulary then, and anything you generate is likely to be gibberish (albeit a rather grammatical gibberish). Maybe you could generate another Markov chain for a large corpus of text not by that author and use it to find appropriate vocabulary that fits the next PoS that should come along in the first method - this might give you reasonably sensible speech in PoS pattern of the author.

Comment: Another possible approach might be to look at the parse tree, and note frequencies of each non-terminal expansion, then use the resulting probabilistic grammar for new sentence syntax tree generation. All this simply brainstorming, haven't actually tried it or read about it.

Comment: I appreciate that, I played with markov trees a little bit.  I am currently working with getting the sentence structure from pos_tag, creating a counter of sentence structures, randomly choosing a structure based on frequency, mapping the words to a dictionary with the key being the POS tag, and then filling it back in.  It creates random sentences with the structure of the original sentences which is starting to give it some of the feel.  I'm not looking for it to make sense as much as for it to capture the delivery.  Markov Chain is interesting tho, I could add this to my implementation.